# Merge 2 arrays into one array with same keys

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to merge the filename into same key.Below are the two arrays, i tried to use array_merge but it is not merging into same keys

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [episode_id] => 2
            [episode_number] => 1
            [series] => 2012
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [episode_id] => 2
            [episode_number] => 2
            [series] => 2013
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => Enq9nNGnMFY
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filename] => Enq9nsdfdsNGnMFY
        )

)
```

The expected output should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [episode_id] => 2
            [episode_number] => 1
            [series] => 2012
            [filename] => Enq9nNGnMFY
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [episode_id] => 2
            [episode_number] => 2
            [series] => 2013
            [filename] => Enq9nsdfdsNGnMFY
        )

)
```

Can anyone help with this !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i was trying with diffreent array functions like array_merge,array_map,etc  but not get it. Can u pls give me the soution

Comment: People who want solutions are not looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($first_array as $key => $item){
$second_array[$key] = array_merge($second_array[$key],$item);
}
```

Second array will include what you wanted.

Comment: Answer id correct but don't you think it's not good to copy first array elements in second. Because this requires 3 times copy. If you copy second array elements into first then only 1 time copy is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($array_1 as $key => $value){
    foreach($array_2[$key] as $key2 => $value2){
        array_push($array_1[$key], $value2);
    }
}
```

$array_1 should then be you're combined array, even if you have more than just filename.

Comment: foreach($episodes_multi as $key=>$multi)
                {
                    print_r(array_push($episodes_multi[$key], $episodes_multi_links[$key]));
                }
                exit; i used like this but output is : 44

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $array_1 = Array
            (Array('episode_id' => 2, 'episode_number' => 1, 'series' => 2012),
            Array('episode_id' => 2, 'episode_number' => 2, 'series' => 2013)
        );

        $array_2 = Array(Array('filename' => 'Enq9nNGnMFY'), Array('filename' => 'Enq9nsdfdsNGnMFY'));

        foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($array_2[$key] as $key2 => $value2) {
                $array_1[$key][$key2] = $value2;
            }
        }



        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($array_1);
        ?>
```

First array is result what you want